# Firefox not working with ububtu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, firefox, browser

I have installed ubuntu and all looks well, the WIFI connected but Firefox browser returns a 'page not found error' when browsing. There is no firewall.

Previously, the machine was running windows 7 and Firefox browser functioned as expected. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have got it working wired suggesting an issue with wireless or wireless driver; driver status reported as up to date.